# How to toggle a keylogger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

here below is my python code that i got from github.

```py
from pynput import keyboard
import json
import sys
key_list = []
x = False  # Value to determine if held


def update_json_file(key_list):
    with open('logs.json', '+wb') as key_log:
        key_list_bytes = json.dumps(key_list).encode()
        key_log.write(key_list_bytes)


def on_press(key):
    global x, key_list
    
    if x == False:
        print(key)
        key_list.append(
            {'Pressed': f'{key}'}
            # f'Key {key} pressed'
        )
        x = True
    if x == True:
        key_list.append(
            {'Held': f'{key}'}
            # f'Key {key} pressed'
        )
    update_json_file(key_list)


def on_release(key):
    print(key)
    global x, key_list
    key_list.append(
        {'Released': f'{key} '}
        # f'Key {key} released'
    )
    if x == True:
        x = False
    update_json_file(key_list)


print("[+] Running Keylogger successfully!\n[!] Saving the key logs in 'logs.json'")

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I want it to toggle keylogging when i hit the ` key back tick.
i don't really need a key logger atm i just need something that can transmit my key presses over usb to my esp8266. I figured i could Frankenstein it for now. but welp.

I have tried

```py
if key=='`':
        sys.exit(0)
```

It did not really work for me.

Comment: Its working for me as is. Tested on OS X

Answer (score 0):

I tested on windows and it seems you need to create a keycode object to compare to, so replace this:

```py
if key=='`':
    sys.exit(0)
```

with this:

```py
if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('`'):
    sys.exit(0)
```

This seems to work for me so it should be fine. Hope this helps.